# How to access state value on page refresh?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

How to access state value on page refresh?

When I refresh the page I could not get state value. So anyone suggests me a solution to this issue. I used below library code to implement a timer in my application.

https://medium.com/@650egor/react-30-day-challenge-day-1-simple-timer-df85d0867553

Thanks.

Comment: So, the tutorial doesn't work or what? Your problem is not so clear. I suggest you to describe well your problem.

Comment: state is getting reset on page refresh, thats just how React works. You could have a look at react-redux, a state managment tool that makes sure your state sticks after refreshes.

Comment: I am implementing time tracker in my project. When I start my tracker then I stored this tracker value into state and when pausing this tracker then change that value into the state. But when I refresh the page then not getting last updated state value. So how can I get state value on page refresh?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't store the state somewhere, it is lost when the site refreshes. You will see the default state again.

It is like a normal script. If you stop it and run it again, it will not "remeber" what it has done before.

You might use the local storage of the browser to store some information for now. But I suggest, looking at some statemanagement-tools to handle the state properly.

Is this the answer you where looking for? Let me know. If not maybe provide the snippet of code you are talking about or the errormessage you are getting.

This is how it works using local storage:

```
state = {
    time: "11:00pm",
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    if (myStorage.state) {
      this.setState(JSON.parse(myStorage.state))
    }
  }

  saveToStorage = () => {
    myStorage.setItem("state", JSON.stringify(this.state))
  }
```

You now have to call the saveToStorage as often as you like. Remeber refreshing is like killing a Videogame right in the middle. If you did not save you will get back to the beginning. Does that help?

Regards

Comment: I am storing time value into state and change that value on another action like pause, stop etc. But I need updated state value on refresh page so how can I get that value on page refresh? I used a code library that is already added in my question.

Comment: See Changes above.

Comment: I am not storing state value to local storage because of my state value change in every second. The main problem is to when timer running and I am refreshing page at that time state value reinitialize with zero. So how can I get last state value of timer when I am refreshing a page.

Comment: Ok, i see. You cannot do that. This is not how a webpage works. The information is stored nowhere. If you don't make an call to an API or save it somewhere it will be lost. I am sorry.